# How to add while loop variable to bootstrap modal php

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table in a while loop that includes a edit button to a modal. What I am trying to achieve is when you click the modal button "edit" the data in the modal will correspond with the correct teacher name. So I am trying to loop the modals and the data in it. What I have done is not working, it is only showing either the first or last value in the array for all modals in the loop.

so the table looks like this

```
| teacher name |    Phone      |    Email      |    Edit    | Delete  |   
|    Mary      | 111-111-1111  | mary@mary.com |    Edit    | Delete  |
|    Rob       | 111-111-1111  | rob@rob.com   |    Edit    | Delete  |
|    Liz       | 111-111-1111  | Liz@Liz.com   |    Edit    | Delete  |
```

When I click on any of the edits the teacher name "Mary" shows up for all of them. But what I want is for Mary to show for the 1st edit, Rob to show for the 2nd edit, and so forth...

**CODE:**

```
<!--TABLES-->
<div id="table" class="table-responsive-sm container">
    <table id="feisHistory" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive table-hover" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">  
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="teacherName" >Teacher Name</th>
                <th id="phone">Phone</th>
                <th id="email">Email</th>
                <th id="edit" data-feild="operate" data-events="operateEvents" data-formatter="operateFormatter" class="d-print-none">Edit</th>
                <th id="delete" data-feild="operate" data-events="operateEvents" data-formatter="operateFormatter" class="d-print-none">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php
          $school_sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE id = '$id'";
          $school_res = mysqli_query($con,$school_sql);
          $school_row = mysqli_fetch_array($school_res);
          $school_name = $school_row["school"];

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `teachers` WHERE school = '$school_name' ORDER BY teacher ASC";
          $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  

         if($res==FALSE){
             die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
         }

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
             $teacherName = $row["teacher"];
             $teacherPhone = $row["phone"];
             $teacherEmail = $row["email"];
             $teacherId = $row["id"];
           ?>
               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $teacherName; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $teacherPhone; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $teacherEmail; ?></td>
                   <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
                   <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-editprofile-modal-lg" style="cursor: pointer; color: #749800;">Edit</a> 


                   <!---MODAL BUTTON-->
                   <div class="col-sm-12 content-btn">
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-12">
                               <div class="formModal1">
                                   <div class="modal fade bd-editprofile-modal-lg" id="editProfile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editProfile" aria-hidden="true">
                                       <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-success modal-lg" role="document">
                                           <div class="modal-content">
                                               <div class="modal-header" style="color: #464646">
                                                   <h5 class="modal-title text-center">Edit Teacher</h5>
                                               </div>
                                               <form id="updateForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="tcol" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                                                    <div class="controls">
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                                                <div class="row">

                                                                   <div class="form-group col-sm-12">

                                                                   <div class="row">
                                                                   <div class="col-sm-3">

                                                                <label> Teacher Name</label>
                                                                 </div>
                                                               <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                 <input id="teacher_name" type="text" name="teacher_name" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $teacherName?>">
                                                                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                                 </div>       
                                                             </div>
                                                         </div>       
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>

                                      <!-- MODAL FOOTER -->
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">Save changes</button>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </td>
       <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
           <a href="delete_teacher?id=<?php echo $teacherId; ?>" style="cursor: pointer; color: #749800;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this teacher? You will never be able to get this information back.');">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr> 

       <?php  } ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

I know my code is sloppy, please don't criticize me too much.. I'm still learning.

Comment: First of all you can not use Modal in while loop..
If you want that data which is you need to edit you have to use AJAX.

Comment: you need use ajax to get the data based on your teacher name

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I'm not good with javascript  or Ajax. Are there articles that you can send me to that can help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the non-ajax version, but you should avoid this since it is rewriting large amount of code (depends on the records), by assigning unique id on each of elements id within the `while` loop, maybe you could use `$teacherId` as an identifier :

```
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         $teacherName = $row["teacher"];
         $teacherPhone = $row["phone"];
         $teacherEmail = $row["email"];
         $teacherId = $row["id"];
       ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo $teacherName; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $teacherPhone; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $teacherEmail; ?></td>
               <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
               <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-editprofile-modal-lg" style="cursor: pointer; color: #749800;">Edit</a> 


               <!---MODAL BUTTON-->
               <div class="col-sm-12 content-btn">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm-12">
                           <div class="formModal1">
                               <div class="modal fade bd-editprofile-modal-lg" id="editProfile<?=$teacherId?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editProfile" aria-hidden="true">
                                   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-success modal-lg" role="document">
                                       <div class="modal-content">
                                           <div class="modal-header" style="color: #464646">
                                               <h5 class="modal-title text-center">Edit Teacher</h5>
                                           </div>
                                           <form id="updateForm<?=$teacherId?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="tcol" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                                            <div class="row">

                                                               <div class="form-group col-sm-12">

                                                               <div class="row">
                                                               <div class="col-sm-3">

                                                            <label> Teacher Name</label>
                                                             </div>
                                                           <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                             <input id="teacher_name<?=$teacherId?>" type="text" name="teacher_name" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $teacherName?>">
                                                             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                             </div>       
                                                         </div>
                                                     </div>       
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>

                                  <!-- MODAL FOOTER -->
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save<?=$teacherId?>">Save changes</button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
       <a href="delete_teacher?id=<?php echo $teacherId; ?>" style="cursor: pointer; color: #749800;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this teacher? You will never be able to get this information back.');">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr> 

   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. But can you tell me why I should avoid doing it this way? What's the concern with rewriting a large amount code? Thanks!

Comment: The main cost of large source code is performance hit (slow), if you are supplying a lot of modal the browser have to do extra work

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with many ways, and i use ajax for this solution.

And this one example how to use ajax to get data for each teacher name.

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
        let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        let tempurl = "";

        // this is example cause i create seperate json data, you can dynamically create select your DB based on id
        if (id == 1){
            tempurl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/19w0nm";
        }else if (id == 2){
            tempurl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/rhq2a";
        }else if (id == 3){
            tempurl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/m4tma";
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            url: tempurl,
            type: "get", 
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {}, //this is data you send to your server
            success: function(res)
            {   
                console.log(res);
                $('#tchName').val(res.name);
                $('#tchPhone').val(res.phone);
                $('#tchEmail').val(res.email);

                $("#modalEdit").modal('show');
            }
        })
    })

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modalEdit").modal('toggle');
        alert('Your data has been update');
    })
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalEdit">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Edit</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="tchName" id="tchName" value=""> 
                        <br>
                        
                        <label for="">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="tchPhone" id="tchPhone" value="">
                        <br>
                        
                        <label for="">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="tchEmail" id="tchEmail" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Testing Table</h3>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center">
                <thead>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo 'Teacher Name 1'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '0211'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'email1@email.com'; ?></td>
                    <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" class="edit" data-id="1">Edit</button> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo 'Teacher Name 2'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '0222'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'email2@email.com'; ?></td>
                    <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" class="edit" data-id="2">Edit</button> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo 'Teacher Name 3'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '0223'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo 'email3@email.com'; ?></td>
                    <td class="d-print-none" style="margin: auto;">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" class="edit" data-id="3">Edit</button> 
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ignore the `tempurl`, you can create function to select and get specific data of your teacher based on teacher name, id or anything else.